# Remote image display is not working (now working using file_get_contents and curl)

Tags: php

**Note: Please read the whole question and understand the scenario carefully before directly jumping into the answer section**

I think this is a very simple problem, which I am not able to figure out.

Basically this one is working just fine.

Example url: http://localhost/test/image.php

Filename: image.php file

```
<?php
// $url = $_GET['url'];
$url = 'http://google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'; 
function data_uri($file) 
{  
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);

    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mime = $finfo->buffer($contents);
    PHP_EOL; 

    $base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
    return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
echo '<img src="' .  data_uri($url) . '" alt="Test image" />';
?>
```

But when I did this (i.e. the below one), it is not working, I can't figure out what went wrong or what I am missing in the process.

Example url: http://localhost/test/displayimage.php

Filename: displayimage.php

```
<img src="http://localhost/test/imageserver.php" alt="image not displaying">
```

Image server file
Filename: imageserver.php

```
<?php
// $url = $_GET['url'];
$url = 'http://google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'; 
function data_uri($file) 
{  
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);

    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mime = $finfo->buffer($contents);
    PHP_EOL; 

    $base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
    return ('data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64);
}
echo data_uri($url);
?>
```

Do I need to set any type of headers or something like that before echo ing data_uri. Any quick suggestions will be welcome to make it work in second url.

**Reason why I am trying to achieve this**

I am trying to display client website content which might be served over http but my server is in SSL and it is giving me this error: Mixed Content: The page at 'http://***/applist.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. And by this methodology, I am trying to serve the http content as a wrapper to my page which is inside my server ie calling page as an https request, so that I can get rid of this warning message and content blocking by the browsers... I'm trying to server the non SSL (http) content to my SSL (https) server like this:

```
<img src="https://mywebsite.com/imageserver.php?url=http://php.net/images/logo.php" />
```

so that it will not block content and doesnot display warning message

**Note: Hope this message will be helpful to others who are facing the same problem**

**Edited: Solution**

Silly mistake i made. I tried to use data: mimetype while displaying image using url. The solution from [Remote image display is not working (now working using file_get_contents and curl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510712/remote-image-display-is-not-working/29511913#29511913) works great and special mention to this answer as well [Remote image display is not working (now working using file_get_contents and curl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510712/remote-image-display-is-not-working/29511913#29511149)

The solution code:

```
<?php
// $url = $_GET['url'];
$url = 'http://google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png';   
function data_uri($file) 
{   
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);

    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mime = $finfo->buffer($contents);

    return array($mime, $contents);
}
list($mime, $content) = data_uri($url);
header('Content-type: '.$mime);
die($content);
?>
```

If someone is interested in the solution using curl rather than `file_get_contents`, the below alternate solution will work perfectly which I have found while waiting for the solution of the above code. (http://ryansechrest.com/2012/07/send-and-receive-binary-files-using-php-and-curl/)

Filename: imageserver_curl.php

```
<?php 
// $url = $_GET['url'];
$url = 'http://php.net/images/logo.php';    
$token = 'N43feedfggsaedwufvworuworjslfurw';

$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'apiToken=' . $token);
$file = curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);

$file_array = explode("\n\r", $file, 2);
$header_array = explode("\n", $file_array[0]);

foreach($header_array as $header_value) {
    $header_pieces = explode(':', $header_value);
    if(count($header_pieces) == 2) {
        $headers[$header_pieces[0]] = trim($header_pieces[1]);
    }
}

header('Content-type: ' . $headers['Content-Type']);
// header('Content-Disposition: ' . $headers['Content-Disposition']); #download option

echo substr($file_array[1], 1);
```

Use it like this

Filename and url: http://localhost/test/displayimage.php

```
<img src="http://localhost/sandbox/securecontent/imageserver_curl.php">
```

Comment: i think here should be .jpg,.png <img src="http://localhost/test/imageserver.php"> not .php

Comment: @satishrajak Nope sorry, I don't think you understood the question properly. I am generating the image dynamically using remote url http://website.com/default-user.png

If you put .jpg, .png, how will to going to write php script in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send remotely inlined data... It's a weird idea, and i'm not sure the browser understand what are you trying to achieve...

imageserver.php

```
<?php
$url = 'http://google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png';   
function data_uri($file) 
{  
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);

    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mime = $finfo->buffer($contents);

    return array($mime, $contents);
}
list($mime, $content) = data_uri($url);
header('Content-type: '.$mime);
die($content);

?>
```

Comment: Perfect working solution. I m still confused why my example was not working. 
Would you mind explaining a bit in note section why is it a weird idea.
For me this is a much needed solution since I want to display http content from client inside my iframe which is served over SSL and it is not allowing http content to display inside my https server page by blocking them. ie this is the error message: was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://***/applist.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Comment: It's a weird idea because this format `'data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . $base64` is used when you put the data of an image directly in an html file. When you download an image via an uri the content is not base64 encoded, it's sent as binary with the 'Content-type' set to the right mime type. (Like i did in the example)
About your error message, it seems that you are trying to send whole html files via this mechanism, it cannot work without rewriting/proxying all URLs that are in the html file. (including the css...)

Comment: Aah yes that makes sense. May be this is caused by my lack of knowledge about data: $mime ... lol .. Okay thanx for help though. Selected as answer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED:**

Your imageserver.php should be:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$url = 'http://php.net/images/logo.php';   
function data_uri($file) 
{  
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    return $contents;
}
echo  data_uri($url);
```

Your view: `<img src="imageserver.php" alt="Test image" />`
Tips: You have to use header content type, because webserver have to know what is your output. It's not necessary to use base64. You must return only the content.

**OLD:**

Tested and working. PHP 5.6.3
JPG and PNG files.

```
$url = 'http://php.net/images/logo.php';   
function data_uri($file) 
{  
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $base64   = base64_encode($contents); 
    return ('data:;base64,' . $base64);
}
echo '<img src="' .  data_uri($url) . '" alt="Test image" />';
```

Comment: Isnt this the same as the first example that I put in my question. Please read the second part of the question carefully and try to mention why is it not working. The first one is working, but second part is not working, why?

Comment: @Kristiyan everyting is working fine. I just want that, if you put your code in this file abc.php and try to access if from another file bbc.php <img src="http://localhost/test/abc.php" it is not working. I want to know why?

Comment: @Yegya I think html does not understand  to load data from url. if you do like this <img src="<?php include('imageserver.php'); ?>" alt=""> it will render image.

Comment: @kamlesh.bar This is a nice suggestion, but in my case I cannot do it that way, since I am generating the link dynamically as a dom using javascript.

Comment: Could not select this as answer, because already selected another as answer, but as an appreciation, I've up vote this answer as well. Cheers. :)